# Taxonomy Category Description

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system, taxonomy

I have a custom post type taxonomy description, which looks like below:

[image: current]

Then in my code, use this to get the title of the category and description

```
                         <?php
                          $term = $wp_query->queried_object;
                          echo '<h3 class="pt30 tester">'.$term->name.'</h3>';

                          echo '<p>'.$term->description.'</p>';
                          ?>
```

My issue is, this is obviously putting it all in `<p>` tags, but i want to be able to add new lines as and when needed. So in the screenshot, you can see there would be new lines.

Any help?

Comment: which word press version are you working on?

Answer (score 1):

Try [CategoryTinymce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/categorytinymce/) Plugin which provide tinymce editor to the category description so you edit your content in both visual and text format and provide new line and any other editor facilities.